# Vagrant host port ignored

Tags: web, workflow, vagrant

In my Vagrantfile I have the definition of my development machine with a private network ip of 192.168.33.10 and a forwarded port of "guest=80, host=8888", but when a run my vagrant enviroment and I try to run curl -i 192.168.33.10:8888 I get an error saying 'Failed connect to 192.168.33.10:8888; connection refused', but when I try to connect to 192.168.33.10:80 everything it's ok.

My Vagrantfile is:

```
Vagrant::configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "precise32"

    config.vm.define :web do |www|
        www.vm.hostname = "apache"
        www.ssh.max_tries = 10
        www.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888  # Apache port
        www.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"

        www.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www", :extra => 'dmode=777,fmode=777'
    end
end
```

Why this happens? is vagrant ignoring the forwarded port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Vagrant Boxes use NAT mode, it means that the guests are behind a `router` (**VirtualBox Networking engine between the host and the guest**) which maps traffic from and to the virtual machine transparently. The guests are invisible and unreachable from the host.

**That's why we need port forwarding.** Otherwise services running on guest wont' be accessible.

In your case, you are using [Private Network](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html), the guest will be assigned a private IP address that ONLY the host can access, which is `192.168.33.10`.

The proper way to access web hosted on the guest is => `http://192.168.33.10` from the host.

You have the port forwarding part in the `Vagrantfile`

```
www.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888  # Apache port
```

It is forwarding guest port 80 to your host's 8888. **Because you are NOT using NAT mode** I am pretty sure it will be ignored. Try to `curl -Is http://localhost:8888`.

> NOTE: even if it still work somehow, you should be accessing web by => `http://localhost:8888/` from your host.